# Memory leak issue occurs when the ValueAnimator animation is not stopped

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms, custom-controls

#### Description

I designed a custom control that will contain content and will be primarily used to display a basic animation before loading the content. We used **ValueAnimator** to start and stop the animation in our custom control. When we placed the custom control inside the Collection view data template, we encountered a memory leak on the Xamarin forms Android platform. We used a garbage collector and added a destructor method to the content page to check for memory leaks. When we investigated the problem, we discovered that the memory leak issue occurs because the animation is not stopped. In the sample when loading the custom control page, we will start the value animator animation but we will not stop anywhere. The memory leak issue is not occurred when we stop the animation before navigating back to the main page.

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. In the custom control page, we have a destructor method to check whether the memory is correctly disposed or not.
2. Keep a break point in the destructor method and run the sample.
3. When navigating back and forth to the custom control page the destructor method will not be raised

#### Expected Behavior

The destructor method should be called when navigating back and forth to the custom control page

#### Actual Behavior

When navigating back and forth to the custom control page the destructor method will not be raised

#### Basic Information

- Platform Target Frameworks: Xamarin.Forms Android

  - Android: Android 11 API 30
- Tested Devices: Redmi Note 8

#### Workaround

[CustomControlSample.zip](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/files/7978179/CustomControlSample.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I had test your code on my device. In addition, I also had done a demo which cointained two pages.

In my demo, the page I custom didn't call the the destructor method when I navigated back to main page. But it will be called after a long time. So this is depending on the GC. When a page disappear doesn't mean it will be collected by the GC at once.